# Unity iOS 10 error

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

i've this problem, what should i do?

Dear developer,

We have discovered one or more issues with your recent delivery for "MyGame". To process your delivery, the following issues must be corrected:

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

This app attempts to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to insert a string in the info.plist file that explains why you are asking for permission to use Apple Music.

So add an explanation for this key NSAppleMusicUsageDescription.

Comment: ok, but where can i find it? Build setting -> packaging -> info.plist File ?    If it is, i add on Debug      info.plist   of on     Release    info.plist?

Comment: Correct.  And you should add it to both.